# Showing multiple tooltips on same element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to put tooltips on an element, that changes based on four buttons on the same page.

```
a.tooltip span {            
  z-index:15;
  position: relative;
  display:none;
  padding:14px 20px;
  margin-top:17.5%;
  margin-left:18%;
  width:300px;
  height:80px;
  line-height:16px;
  border-radius:2px;        
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 3px #666;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

a.tooltip:hover span{
  display:inline;
  position:absolute; 
  border:2px solid #666;
  color:black;
  background:white repeat-x 0 0;
}
```

This is my tooltip. I works just fine, but I can't hide it, when I want another tooltip to be displayed.

How do I disable this tooltip and show another one, based on the buttons I clicked? Tooltip1 has to be hidden when Tooltip2 is shown and vice versa.

Dr. Google didn't help.

**Image for clarification** :
[image: Image for clarification]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change tooltip content with

```
 $(".tooltip-selector").tooltip("option", "content", "New Content");
```

and bind this to your button's click

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is there any pure CSS solution?

Comment: I dont think it would be a good way since you still have to toggle those classes somehow with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.btn1').click(function(){
  $('.tooltip').addClass('btn1');
  $('.tooltip').removeClass('btn2');
  
  });
 $('.btn2').click(function(){
  $('.tooltip').addClass('btn2');
  $('.tooltip').removeClass('btn1');
  
  });

 
 });
```

```css
   a.tooltip span {            
z-index:15;
position: relative;
display:none;
padding:14px 20px;
margin-top:17.5%;
margin-left:18%;
width:300px;
height:80px;
line-height:16px;
border-radius:2px;        
box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 3px #666;
opacity: 0.8;}

a.tooltip.btn1:hover span.btn1{
display:inline;
position:absolute; 
border:2px solid #666;
color:black;
background:white repeat-x 0 0;}

a.tooltip.btn2:hover span.btn2{
display:inline;
position:absolute; 
border:2px solid #666;
color:black;
background:white repeat-x 0 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="tooltip">1
 <span class="btn1">1</span>
<span class="btn2">2</span>
</a>
 <button class="btn1">1</button>
 <button class="btn2">2</button>
```